# Get the text between two custom tags from a string using regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I have a string that I want to get text from:

```
var text = "<p>This is awesome and</p> <p>some random</p> and <custom>complex boring text</custom> <p>I</p> <custom>really need to clean</custom> up my room. that feel"
```

I want to get the text from all the `<custom />` tags in a array. I am trying to get this result:

```
['complex boring text', 'really need to clean']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, [never ever use RegEx to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). To achieve this you can create a jQuery object from the `text` and then `filter()` out the `custom` elements before creating an array of their text using `map()`. Try this:

```
var arr = $(text).filter('custom').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();
console.log(arr);
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/bh66tL1j/)

Comment: Thanks +1 for letting me know about regex to HTML

Comment: @Rory: Secondly: never answer "gimme-code" questions. [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'd rather help someone than simply close a question for asking about an incorrect solution.

Comment: As people say, fair enough.